# Grunt task to compile Bootstrap 4 custom scss

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I have followed B4 docs and created a _custom.scss file to get a customized css file. I have run a grunt task by executing Gruntfile.js that comes with B4 download. I see that in css folder all files got overwritten because of a new modified date. But comparing a content of new bootstrap.css with the original doesn't show any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Update. I have imported _custom.scss. But seems like I am having errors:

```
D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6>grunt
>> Local Npm module "grunt-sass" not found. Is it installed?

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "exec:sass" (exec) task

> bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 sass D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6
> node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap.scss dist/css/bootstrap.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-grid.scss dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css

>> Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
>> Wrote Source Map to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\dist\css\bootstrap.css.map
>> Wrote CSS to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\dist\css\bootstrap.css
>> Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
>> Wrote CSS to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\dist\css\bootstrap-grid.css
>> Wrote Source Map to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\dist\css\bootstrap-grid.css.map
>> Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
>> Wrote CSS to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\dist\css\bootstrap-reboot.css
>> Wrote Source Map to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\dist\css\bootstrap-reboot.css.map

Running "exec:sass-docs" (exec) task

> bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 sass-docs D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6
> node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --precision 6 docs/assets/scss/docs.scss docs/assets/css/docs.min.css

>> Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
>> Wrote CSS to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\docs\assets\css\docs.min.css
>> Wrote Source Map to D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\docs\assets\css\docs.min.css.map

Running "exec:postcss" (exec) task

> bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 postcss D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6
> postcss --config grunt/postcss.js --replace dist/css/*.css


Running "exec:clean-css" (exec) task

> bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 clean-css D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6
> cleancss --skip-advanced --source-map --output dist/css/bootstrap.min.css dist/css/bootstrap.css && cleancss --skip-advanced --source-map --output dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && cleancss --skip-advanced --source-map --output dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css


Running "exec:clean-css-docs" (exec) task

> bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 clean-css-docs D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6
> cleancss --skip-advanced --source-map --output docs/assets/css/docs.min.css docs/assets/css/docs.min.css


Running "babel:dev" (babel) task
Warning: D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-strip\lib\index.js:4
      ModuleDeclaration(path) {
                       ^
Unexpected token ( Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2017-03-11 07:32:29 UTC-6)
exec:sass             1.6s  ███████████████████████ 28%
exec:sass-docs       735ms  ███████████ 13%
exec:postcss          1.4s  ████████████████████ 24%
exec:clean-css        1.3s  ███████████████████ 23%
exec:clean-css-docs  687ms  ██████████ 12%
Total 5.7s
```

Any idea what that might be?

Update 2.
I ran npm install --save-dev grunt-sass and I am not getting:

> > Local Npm module "grunt-sass" not found. Is it installed?

But:
 Running "babel:dev" (babel) task
    Warning: D:\bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-strip\lib\index.js:4
          ModuleDeclaration(path) {
                           ^
    Unexpected token ( Use --force to continue.

```
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Is still happening.

Update 3. Used -- force to comlete. Dont

Thanks

Comment: Did you @import _custom.scss in bootstrap.scss?

Comment: Oops, I think I missed it, thanks!

Comment: Just updated my post.